# SQL select statement

Tags: sql, select

in a string array i have a variable amount of values.
how will an sql statement look if i want to select all the records that are equal with the array variables.

it will look something this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+ variable amount of elements in the String array like: Steven, Mike, John ..... +"'"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for the IN( ) operator.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('chris', 'bob', 'bill');`

Answer (score 1):

This? (obviously the "OR username='xxx' is repeated for as many items as you require)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='item1' OR username='item2' OR username='item3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Every one above me is corrrect! There are multiple ways of doing this! A simple google search for 'mysql statement variables' yield tons of help full results including:

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread126895.html

Just treat your array like a standard varible with [a number] on the end!

Two tips come from this:

Google / Search your problem first 9 times out of 10 someone else has had the same problem and found a working solution!

And be prepared to look at the answers on here with in 5 mins. This forums probably the quickest you'll ever see. The only thing that slows the  community down is typing ! :P

Hope that Helps,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, although less efficient, can be used if parsing the string apart is problematic...

```
DECLARE @listOfNames VARCHAR(2000)
SET @ListOfNames = 'JOE,KELLIE,PETE'

SELECT * FROM users WHERE charindex(","+userName+",",","+@listOfNames+",") > 0
```

This approach is slower than either of the other answers, but can save you from using dynamic SQL to build a SQL query based on the list of names passed in...